# Expression of type doesn't conform to Expected type B

Tags: scala

I have following code to understand covariant and lower bound, I intentionally make the code have compiling errors.

The `getOrElse` works, which is similar from the `getOrElse` method of Option[+T].

I would ask why `getOrElse2` and `getOrElse3` don't work to better understand covariant and lower bound.

The compiling error is pasted as comments in the code:

```
class  MyOption[+A](val x: A) {
  def get():A = x

  //similar to Option.getOrElse,which works
  def getOrElse[B>:A ](default: => B): B = {
    if (x != null) x else  default
  }

  //Compiling Error: Expression of type A doesn't conform to Expected type B
  def getOrElse2[B, A<:B ](default: => B): B = {
    if (x != null) x else  default
  }

  //Covariant type A occurs in controvariant position in type A of value B
  def getOrElse3[B <: A](default:=>B): A = {
    if (x != null) x else  default
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.`getOrElse3[B <: A]`: means the type `B` **controvariant** `A` that's `B` is the **subtype/lowerbound** of `A`, this is not allowed for **covariant type** `A`, Since **covariant type** only enable the **super type** bound for type `A`. and also this is equal to:

```
//Error:covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value default
def getOrElse3(default: A): A = {
  if (x != null) x else default
}
```

so why **covariance** for the **Option** type? this is for binding `A` to **supertype A**, like `Some(1)` can be used by the method which accept parameter: `Option[AnyVal]`.

2.`def getOrElse2[B, A<:B ]`: `A<:B` it means define a new type `A` of subtype `B`(not the class level type `A`). and since you are returning `x` of class generic type `A` to the type `B`, the compiler should throw the **type mismatch** error.

Comment: I understand that [B<:A] means B is the subtype/lowerbound of A, do you mean that [B<:A] also means the type B controvariant A? I thought upper bound has nothing to do covariant or controvariant. Also, I don't understand  `covariant type only enable the super type bound for type A`.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying `[A <: B]` for method `getOrElse2`, you're defining a new local type `A` unrelated to the original type `A` which `x` belongs to, as explained in @chengpohi's answer.

As for method `getOrElse3`, `[B <: A]` is going against [trait Function1](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html)'s definition which demands its argument to be contravariant:

```
trait Function1[-T1, +R] extends AnyRef {
  abstract def apply(v1: T1): R
  // ...
}
```

With the covariant [+A], for a subtype `S` of `A` an instance of MyOption[S](x: S) can replace an instance of MyOption[A](x: A); but getOrElse3[S] cannot replace getOrElse3[A] due to `Function1` argument's contravariance requirement.  For the same reason, the following method will fail the compiler as well:

```
// Compiling Error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value default
def printDefault(default: A): Unit = {
  println(default)
}
```

To preserve your covariant [+A], making `A` the lower bound like in your first `getOrElse` method avoids conflicting `Function1` argument's contravariance.

Comment: I don't understand the statement `With the covariant [+A], a subtype B of A can replace A, thus violating Function1 argument's contravariance requirement`. I am brain burning now.

Comment: @Tom, sorry I wasn't clear.  I've refined the relevant statement.

Comment: Thanks @leo-c, I could understand MyOption[S](x: S) can replace an instance of MyOption[A](x: A), this is covariance; Also, I understand, getOrElse3[S] cannot replace getOrElse3[A] (getOrElse3[A] should be able to replace getOrElse3[S])because Fucntion1's argument  is controvariance.Given these two facts,I still don't understand where the problem of my getOrElse3 method lies,maybe i need some code to help illustrate the problem(eg, presume it's definition is correct first)

Comment: You might want to take a look at the example of `class Box[+A] { def set(x: A) : Box[A] = ... }` in this [blog](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/software-teams/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala).

Comment: Thanks @leo-c. I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434571/understand-the-type-parameter-and-variance-rules. Could you please help take a look? Thanks